# Rangy.js - createClassApplier with Multiple Classes

Tags: javascript, rangy

I am trying to create a class applier that would wrap the selection in the following element:

```
<code class="mainClass selector1 selector2">Selected Content</code>
```

I am doing the following:

```
var Applier = rangy.createClassApplier("mainClass",
{
    elementTagName: "code",
    elementProperties:
    {
        className: [ "selector1", "selector2" ]
    }
});

Applier.toggleSelection();
```

This yields the following:

```
<code class="mainClass selector1,selector2">Selected Content</code>
```

What is the syntax to create the applier so that it does what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like this was not implemented ([see here](https://github.com/timdown/rangy/issues/353)). To fix it, change line 69 in range.classApplied to this:

`if (typeof el.classList == "object" && typeof className == "object")`